# Submit a form when at least 1 of 5 complex inputs is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Summary:** I have a form with 5 inputs: 3 char inputs that only accept alphabet text, 1 date input, and 1 char input that only accepts numbers. When the user clicks the submit button, *at least* 1 of the 5 inputs needs to be valid in order to execute.

**Effort:** I've set up validation using if-else on keyup for each of the inputs, where the 3 alphabet inputs require a length less than 50 and greater than 2. The date input must be lower than 12/31/2050 and the number input requires 7 characters. My consideration is that I should create a separate function for each validation method, and return true/false. This way, the submit button can look for the boolean value vs. a new set of operators.

This is what each input look like:

```
<div class="adv-searchbar">
   <div class="adv-searchbar__wrapper">
      <div class="adv-searchbar__wrapper__search-box">
         <span class="search__column-1">
            <input class="alphInput1" placeholder="" value="">
         </span>
         <span class="search__column-1">
            <input class="alphInput2" placeholder="" value="">
         </span>
         <span class="search__column-1">
            <input class="alphInput3" placeholder="" value="">
         </span>
         <span class="search__column-2">
            <input class="dateInput" placeholder="" value="">
         </span>
         <span class="search__column-2">
            <input class="numInput" placeholder="" value="">
         </span>
         <button type="submit" class="">submit</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Input 1 through 3 (only alphabet, lengths < 50 and > 2):

```
$('.alphInput1, .alphInput2, .alphInput3').keyup(function (e) {
   let input = $(this);
   this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, '');
   if (this.value.length <= 50 && this.value.length >= 2) {
       console.log(this.value);
       $(this).css('border-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.33');
   }
   else{
       $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
   }
 });
```

Input 4 (max: 12/31/2050):

```
$('.dateInput').keyup(function (e) {
   let input = $(this);
   if (input.prop('max') < input.val()) {
       $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
   } else $(this).css('border-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.33');
});
```

Input 5 (length must be 7):

```
$('.numInput').keyup(function () {
   var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
   var newVal = '';
   if (val.length > 4) {
       this.value = val;
   }
   if ((val.length > 3) && (val.length < 6)) {
       newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
       val = val.substr(3);
   }
   if (val.length > 5) {
       newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
       newVal += val.substr(3, 2) + '-';
       val = val.substr(5);
   }
   newVal += val;
   this.value = newVal.substring(0, 11);
});
```

So this is the function I am creating and where I need help:

```
function checkFields() {
   // get all inputs
   let searchInputs = $('.adv-searchbar input');
   console.log(searchInputs);

   // check each input value
   var inputValues = searchInputs.map(function () {
      return $(this).val();
   }).toArray();
   console.log(inputValues);

   // if any input has correct value, enable button

   // else wait for a valid value
 }
```

Up to this point, I can see all the values of the inputs in the `inputValue` array, if I put the function in one of the keyup functions. Conceptually, I am struggling with how I should progress. Is this the most efficient / easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't look bad. Proably identifying the elements by properties instead of classes would be a more appropiate way (like instead of alphInput3, add a property
like validate-alphanumeric

```
<input validate-alphanumeric validate-rule-length=3 ...
```

or.. you could always use an existent framework like https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: I'd prefer not to use any framework for the time being, but how would I modify the last function: checkFields(), if I were to use these validations?